# how to get a successful response to a manifest request created from an Inventor Assembly file for a svf file

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

we don’t get a complete answer from the manifest, and because of this downloaded swf file it weighs only 2kb.

[This is my request code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaiJ8.png)

Comment: What is the actual response you get from the request? And why do you think it is incomplete? What exactly are you trying to achieve with the data from the request?

Comment: Also, note that an SVF (the file format used by Forge Viewer) file is just a "manifest" that references other assets (geometry data, textures, property database, etc.), so its size can be quite small.

Comment: But is it possible to download the received svf file from the manifest, we tried to download but received only a file with a size of 2 kilobytes

Comment: in our answer we only got a 3D role, we need 2D and 3D.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the manifest you get in the response?

Comment: There are different tools that allow you to extract SVF from your Forge models, for example, https://extract.autodesk.io, or an extension for vscode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools.

Comment: This is the received response from the request for the svf file. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/633901802709843970/638998878988926976/unknown.png

Comment: I believe that's the (complete) SVF response. Let me provide an answer on what can be done with this data.

Answer (score 0):

The data you see in the [response](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/633901802709843970/638998878988926976/unknown.png) is actually complete. The SVF file is basically a ZIP file containing two files - *metadata.json* and *manifest.json* - and potentially other files as well. Typically, the *manifest.json* file references other assets stored "next to it".

I'm working on a utility for parsing the SVF as well as all its referenced assets, maybe you can use it for inspiration: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils/blob/develop/src/svf/reader.ts#L57-L389.

Comment: thank you very much, it turns out we already got what we wanted but did not understand

Comment: @petr-broz Is there a way to get all the referenced assets of an SVF in the manifest itself? To clarify, I'm asking about the manifest from the translation job.